# unable to Initialize Jquery DataTables on button click Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Here is my HTML which is a partial view,

```
<table id="table_id" class="table table-inverse">
            <thead class="thead-inverse">
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>StructureName</th>
                    <th>FieldType</th>
                    <th>DataType</th>
                    <th>IsHeirarchy</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                        <td>@item.One</td>
                        <td>@item.Two</td>
                        <td>@item.Three</td>
                        <td>@item.Four</td>
                        <td><a href="#"> Edit</a></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I'm initializing [DataTable](http://datatables.net/) as shown below,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#table_id').DataTable();
        });
</script>
```

Above code is working fine and data table is initialized on page load by calling controller method to populate data.

Now, On click event I'm calling ajax method to pass input parameters to load data as shown below,

```
$(function () {
    $('#searchbtn').on('click', function () {          
        var url = '@Url.Action("LoadGridData", "Home")';
        var clientID = $('#Clientdata').val();
        var serviceId = $('#SelectService').val();
        $.ajax({               
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",                
            success: function (services) {
                $('#searchResults').load(url, { intclientId: clientID, intserviceID: serviceId });
                $('#table_id').DataTable();
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Here, while debugging i can see that `$('#table_id').DataTable();` DataTable is initialized but its not staying.

Not sure whats happening. Any help appreciated :)

Comment: what do you mean by `not staying` ?

Comment: Don't initialize it in success function initialize it before jquery click event

Comment: can you tell me what is searchresults

Comment: is the #searchResults the container of your table ?

Comment: yes, #searchResult is just a <div> container

Comment: @MaVRoSCy - basically DataTable is not getting initialized.

Comment: do you get any error or worning in your console when you try to reinitialise it? like `Cannot reinitialise DataTable.` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are initializing the plugin before the table is loaded. You have to wait for the HTML to be loaded. Try this

```
    success: function (services) {
                    $('#searchResults').load(url, { intclientId: clientID, intserviceID: serviceId },function(){
                       $('#table_id').DataTable(); // now we apply plugin when the elment is available.
                    });                        
                }
```

Comment: spot on! The jquery.load() makes the request and you imediately try to initialise the table before the data from server comes to your view... +1

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) Perfect spot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can **initialize** the **DataTable** twice.

But you can pass the new data from ajax like:

```
$('#table_id').DataTable( {
   data: dataSet, //from ajax result
   columns: [
       { title: "Name" },
       { title: "Position" },
       ......
   ]
});
```

As stated in Documentation. [Javascript sourced data](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

Comment: problem was with the way I initialized the DataTable function. Not with the data. Thanks for the help anyways! :)